# json into list with Gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a Json like below:

```
{
 "searchResults": {
"searchCriteria": {
  "location": {
    "originalLocation": null
  },
  "startAndEndDate": {
    "start": "2016-10-06T00:00:00",
    "end": "2016-10-09T00:00:00"
  },

"solution": [
  {
    "resultID": "O1MDc1MD",
    "selected": false,
    "charges": {
      "localCurrencyCode": "USD",
      "averagePricePerNight": 153
    },
    "starRating": 3.5
  },
  {
    "resultID": "0MDc1MD",
    "selected": false,
    "charges": {
      "localCurrencyCode": "USD",
      "averagePricePerNight": 153
    },
    "starRating": 3.5
  }
  ....
```

I have class with attributes starRating and averagePricePerNight which essentially formulates into my POJO.

```
class ResponseModel {
 Int starRating;  Int averagePricePerNight
}
```

I want to parse this JSON and return a List containing :

```
List(ResponseModel(3.5,900), ResponseModel(3.5,100), ResponseModel(4.5,1000))
```

I tried to get the json as a List but then i am unable to find examples to get two elements from JSon.

Comment: First off, your POJO is not valid Java. Secondly, you haven't shown that you have tried anything, so why should we help you?

Comment: @rmlan : Just came out of scala so missed it on writing the class here. I tried getting the data but either i can get starRating or averagePricePerNight, I have been unable to get both.

Comment: That still is not Java code. And it would be easier to provide an answer if your JSON was valid.

Comment: Perhaps you should try this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom deserializer:

```
class Deserializers {
     public static ResponseModel responseModelDeserializer(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) {

        JsonObject obj1 = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject obj2 = obj1.get("charges").getAsJsonObject();

        double starRating = obj1.get("starRating").getAsDouble();
        int averagePricePerNight = obj2.get("averagePricePerNight").getAsInt();

        return new ResponseModel(starRating, averagePricePerNight);
    }
}
```

Register it when building `Gson`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(ResponseModel.class,
        (JsonDeserializer<ResponseModel>) Deserializers::responseModelDeserializer
        // ^^^ Cast is needed because the parameter has type Object
    )
    .create();
```

(Other options include, besides a method reference, are; lambda, anonymous class, or just a regular class. But this one is my favourite.)

Parse your json:

```
// Get root json object
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(input).getAsJsonObject();

Type tt = new TypeToken<List<ResponseModel>>() {}.getType();
// Get array
List<ResponseModel> mo = gson.fromJson(root.get("solution"), tt);

System.out.println(mo); // [3.5 : 153, 3.5 : 153]
```

Where ResponseModel is:

```
class ResponseModel {
    private final double starRating;
    private final int averagePricePerNight;

    public ResponseModel(double starRating, int averagePricePerNight) {
        this.starRating = starRating;
        this.averagePricePerNight = averagePricePerNight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s : %s", starRating, averagePricePerNight);
    }
}
```

I made `starRating` a `double` since it seems to be one in your example.